# Handle missing properties in a general purpose api using javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am working with a general purpose REST api that happens to exclude properties where the values are null (Spring Jackson @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL))

Since I am just using Javascript (vue.js & axios) and generally not privy to what may or maynot be returned, what is the best way to handle missing properties in the axios

```
response.data.expectedProprtyIsNotThere
```

in a general way so that is can be applied to all response objects without any additional code or duplication? I think I might be ok with have a default value of null or empty string.

I am not using any sdk and using the response data object directly.

Comment: Can you show the code in which you're retrieving the potentially `null`, or non-existent, properties? I'd suggest a ternary (`let variableName = response.data.expectedProperty ? response.data.expectedProperty : sensibleDefaultValueIfPropertyAbsent;`), but that would presumably depend on the type of data that's missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a default response

```
var default = {...};
```

And before you use your response you insert the missing properties using `Object.assign()`:

```
response = Object.assign({},default,response);
```

Comment: Good solution, default properties with default values for properties. I just started using Object.assign in other areas, and over-looked this option here.